# How to pass a function as an argument, with arguments?

Tags: c++, c, function, callback

So, I'm playing with callbacks in GNUTLS.

I want to pass my function, `handleSNI` to a function, but I also want to pass on some other important arguments as well(to handleSNI when it is called).

I could just do them outside the functions in global variables, but that isn't thread safe.

Is it possible? If not, how can one accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using a class? Because if you are not, it would be easier to implement what you are talking about with a class.

Comment: @GabrielMello It has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GnuTLS supports user defined arguments in callbacks. For the push and pull function you set them via [`gnutls_transport_set_ptr`](http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Core-TLS-API.html#gnutls_005ftransport_005fset_005fptr). You pass a pointer to a struct containing your data and use that in your callback.

On a more general level the answer is: If your library doesn't support user defined parameters, you are out of luck. In C there is no way to cheat an extra parameter in. If you ever find such a library, do your self a favor and don't use it. And if there is no alternative you could use threadsafe containers or thread local storage. But it is really ugly.

Comment: Doesn't set_ptr equivilant to setting the sockfd in set_int?

Comment: A __thread prefixed global solved the issue nicely.